# Force db4o to call constructor

Tags: c#, .net, db4o, object-oriented-database

Is there any way to tell db4o to call class default constructor while activating objects? I tried following code but it didn't work:

```
    private static void ConfigureDatabase()
    {
        var config = Db4oEmbedded.NewConfiguration();
        config.Common.ObjectClass(typeof(Device)).CallConstructor(true);
        using(var db = Db4oEmbedded.OpenFile(config, Helper.GetDataFilePath("index"))) { }
    }
```

The constructor of Device is never called when retrieving objects from database.

and here's how Device constructor looks like:

```
    public Device()
    {
        connectionType = ConnectionType.Disconnected;
    }
```

Any help would be appreciated.

**UPDATE**
BWT, I also wanted to know if it's possible to tell db4o to call constructor for every objects, without having to write one by one for each type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try [this](http://community.versant.com/documentation/reference/db4o-7.12/net2/reference/Content/configuration/common/calling_constructors.html)?

```
IEmbeddedConfiguration configuration = Db4oEmbedded.NewConfiguration();
configuration.Common.CallConstructors = true;
```

Comment: I just found it. Thanks Bob :)